# ExecWB not available in IE9 on VS2010

Tags: vb.net, browser, internet-explorer-9

I have a program in VB.NET that has a webbrowser contorl. I wanted to zoom on a page and i found a tutorial online that involved something like this

`webbrowser1.ActiveXInstance.ExecWB(OLECMD...`

When i went on and typed it on, there's nothing called `ExecWB`.

Why is that? Is it because i'm using IE9?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

I think the problems with IE9. When i tried the same thing in VB6 (with a different code that is), i get an error "Method ExecWB failed to initialize" or something like that.
So, how can i fix this?

Comment: turn off Option Strict first.

Comment: @ShengJiang蒋晟 no, turning off option strict doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Security setup.

Initialization and script execution of an ActiveX control which are not marked if safe even if it performs a script.

It operated, when it was except invalidity.